# Magento 2 API get product price

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I'm building an iOS application for my store, and I'm looking for a way to get the correct price of an actual product.

Looking at the API I only find requests to get raw product information.
http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html

However, if used this, I'll have to recreate the rules used for tier/group pricing in my app.
It would be nice to just send the customer group, quantity and product SKU and get the correct price.
Have I missed anything similar to this in the API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as now REST API are not supporting catalog rules.

Check this module for a fix: https://github.com/magespecialist/m2-MSP_APIEnhancer

Comment: My store has 2 currencies. Is there a way to get the converted price of the product?